# Separating js from angular controllers (do I create a directive for this?)

Tags: angularjs

I'm using a lot of built in angular directives such as ng-repeat with the html. I already separated the UI component to a different HTML file using ng-include. How do I separate out the js from the controller?

html (ui/hotkeys.ui.html)

```
<div ng-controller="AddManagerController as vm">

<button class="btn hotkey" ng-change="vm.changed($index)" ng-class="{'btn-danger': $index === 1, 'btn-info': $index === 2, 'btn-primary': $index === 3, 'btn-success': $index === 4, 'btn-warning': $index === 5, 'btn-inverse': $index === 6 }" ng-if="hotkeys !== null" ng-model="vm.credentials.groups[$index]" ng-repeat="hotkeys in vm.showGroups track by $index" tabindex="-1" type="button" style="margin-right: 4px" uib-btn-checkbox>
  <svg width="42" height="42" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="4" stroke="black" fill="white" ng-if="$index === 1 || $index === 3 || $index === 5" stroke-width="1"/>
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="4" stroke="black" fill="white" ng-if="$index ===4 || $index === 5 || $index === 6" stroke-width="1"/>
    <circle cx="10" cy="20" r="4" stroke="black" fill="white" ng-if="$index === 6" stroke-width="1"/>
    <circle cx="10" cy="30" r="4" stroke="black" fill="white" ng-if="$index === 2 || $index === 3 || $index === 4 || $index === 5 || $index === 6" stroke-width="1"/>
    <circle cx="30" cy="10" r="4" stroke="black" fill="white" ng-if="$index === 2 || $index === 3 || $index === 4 || $index === 5 || $index === 6" stroke-width="1"/>
    <circle cx="30" cy="20" r="4" stroke="black" fill="white" ng-if="$index === 6" stroke-width="1"/>
    <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="4" stroke="black" fill="white" ng-if="$index === 4 || $index === 5 || $index === 6" stroke-width="1"/>
  </svg>
</button>

</div>
```

This is the code I want to load from another js file instead of keeping all this in the controller.

```
/* ============ HOTBAR ============ */
var enableHotbar = true;
$document.bind('keypress', function (e) {
    //console.log(e.key);
    var key = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    if (key == 1 || key == 2 || key == 3 || key == 4 || key == 5 || key == 6) {
        //alert(key);
        $scope.$broadcast('keypress', e, e.which);
    }
});
$scope.keyList = []; //["1","2", "3"];
$scope.$on('keypress', function (event, key) {
  var easyToReadKeyFromKeycode = String.fromCharCode(key.charCode);
  if (enableHotbar && (document.activeElement.id !== 'manager-phone') && (document.activeElement.id !== 'manager-name')) {
    vm.credentials.groups.forEach(function(group, index){
      if (easyToReadKeyFromKeycode === (index).toString()) {
        vm.credentials.groups[index] = !vm.credentials.groups[index];
      }
    })
  }
  $scope.keyList.push(String.fromCharCode(key.charCode));
  //console.log($scope.keyList);
  $scope.$apply();
});

  // add ng-focused and ng-blurred to any input element requiring numbers
    $scope.focused = function (e) {
      enableHotbar = false;
    }
    $scope.blurred = function (e) {
      enableHotbar = true;
    }

    // Manager Name disables keys 1 through 6
    $scope.keyPressed = function(e) {
      console.log(e);
      if ((e.keyCode >= 49 && e.keyCode <= 54)) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }


/* ================================= */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more options to separate JS from controller (to another controller honestly). If you want some singleton usage, you should create [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) for it. If you want some special functionality without separate view create a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) or [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). And if your special functionality has some view (HTML) create [component](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component). This is angularJS basic